# awaitReactions filter not working since upgrading to discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
getRedCardChannel.send({ embeds: [cardEmbed] })
                .then(message => {
                    // Send message
                    console.log('Message sent to Channel');

                    // Add checkmark emoji for appprover to confirm
                    message.react('✅')
                        .then(() => {
                            message.react('❌');
                            console.log('Confirmation buttons added');
                        });

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        // Define a confirmation filter that only the approver ID can activate
                        const confirmFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                            return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && (user.id === getAdminId || user.id === getApproverId); // hard-coded my User ID to override
                        };

                        // Await a reaction to the message from the filter (approver and approved emotes)
                        message.awaitReactions({ filter: confirmFilter, max: 1 })
                            .then(collected => {
                                console.log(user);
                                const approvalReaction = collected.first();
                                // In here, write what we want to do when user confirms the card
                                // If Green, else if Red...
                                if (approvalReaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                                    // If accepted, increment the counter for approved and remove a provisional 
                                    message.react('');
                                    console.log('Approved');
                                    console.log(`${reaction.message.author.tag}'s message "${reaction.message.content}" gained a confirmed red card!`);

                                } else {
                                    // If rejected, delete the message
                                    console.log('Rejected');
                                    approvalReaction.message.delete({ timeout: 1000 })
                                        .then(() => {
                                            getRedCardChannel.send('Provisional card removed')
                                                .then(deleteMessage => {
                                                    deleteMessage.delete({ timeout: 3000 });
                                                });
                                        });
                                };
                            });
                    }, 3000);
                });
```

The above sends a message to a channel, gets the bot to react to the message, and then waits for a determined user (in the filter) to choose one of the 2 reactions.

What's happening at the moment is that ANY user can react and trigger the if statement at the bottom. Also ANY emoji can be added to the message and it triggers the else logic

I also had to add a delay of 3 seconds around the awaitReactions function because it was triggering AS THE BOT WAS ADDING THE REACTIONS... So the filter is definitely not working because the bot's user ID is not getAdminId or getApproverId

I have removed some of the other code for what the function does (update a json file to store data) as my focus is working out why the filter doesn't work

Comment: Voted to close as you don't use the `filter` key in the options object at all. `awaitReactions({ confirmFilter, max: 1 })` should be `awaitReactions({ filter: confirmFilter, max: 1 })`

Comment: Cheers - hadn't thought of that as it worked fine in Discord.js 12. I have updated the code with the filter key and tested it on my end and still ignoring the filter provided

Comment: Oh, I see. What are `getAdminId` and `getApproverId`? Are these strings? Also, are you sure you don't want to collect from `getAdminId` (`user.id !== getAdminId`)?

Comment: Yeah sorry - I also changed it back to user.id === getAdminId (noticed just before you commented!) because I think I was playing around with the filter to make sure it was collecting the reaction from the wrong user so I could confirm the filter wasn't working. The getAdminId and getApproverId are consts that get these values from the config file - they are just strings, yeah - hardcoded user IDs. So how it works currently on v12 is that it will ignore reactions from anybody that is not those two Users

Comment: Ah I think you might have sorted it for me - since adding the filter key and changing the filter to be correct, I moved the location of the filter back to where it used to be (further up the file just before the embed is sent - and I think that might have fixed it (don't know why, can't see any scope issue! But maybe it was the missing filter key after all??) Thank you for your comments!